# Which of Files.readAllLines or Files.lines method is faster for file reading?

Tags: java, java-io

I have a file reader, which returns the lines of a file as an `Object[]`. I am using the `lines` method. Would it be faster to use `readAllLines`? I do not use the stream for anything else, but I want `currentBookData` to be a `String[]` or `Object[]`.

```
package input;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReadFile {

    public static Object[] currentBookData;

    public static void getBookData(String path) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
            currentBookData = stream.toArray();
        }

        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
readAllLines()
```

puts everything in memory in one time so nothing can be faster than that. Don't use it if your file is large.

Comment: What if I have a 10,000 line file, would lines be superior? I'm assuming yes, because it does not do it all at once.

Comment: I think if you have enough memory readAllLines() will beat everytime. why don't you try both with a large file and measure the time spent with System.nanotime() ?

Comment: Test complete. Results are on my answer. Strangly enough, the results say it took about 9000 seconds. While this is not true, the results are probably able to judge the faster method. Does the decimal show on the println method?

Comment: How much large mean large? :)

Answer (score -2):

For large files, `lines` is actually faster. The results were recorded with the `nanoTime` method. Here are the results:

`lines`: 890453203.00649

`readAllLines`: 891095615.58289

For the smaller files, readAllLines is faster.

Comment: `0.0006` of a second faster is hardly a conclusive benchmark result, especially when I/O is involved! If you want to actually benchmark code in Java please use a framework like [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Comment: You are correct, but I ran the test multiple times. These are the averages of the data. lines was faster each lime.

Comment: Chances are that your "benchmark" is spending most of its time doing JVM warmup stuff.  Your measurements are most likely not meaningful.

Comment: Once again, you are correct. I do not have the free time for a proper test right now.

Comment: @CaffeineToCode thanks for your efforts. What is the size of the large file you used.